# Porque no tengo objetos del tipo SmartDevices

Tags: genexus

recién instale genexus y quiero crear un objeto SD, pero en la ventana para crear un nuevo objeto no aparece ningún objeto del tipo SD, agregue un objeto 'Panel' pero despues de esto aparece:

> warning: SD application cannot be launched because no SD main objects are present in the Knowledge Base.

Y un error del IIS.

> Error HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error
> No se puede obtener acceso a la página solicitada

Agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

El warning te está indicando que no tienes en la KB un objeto SD que sea main, es decir, que pueda ser tu "ejecutable" de la aplicación.

En la versión 17 vas a encontrar los "Panel" como objetos SD, por lo tanto, si a ese Panel que creaste, le indicas que sea main (Main Program = true), entonces ya tendrás el "ejecutable" de tu aplicación.

Te comparto algunos links del Wiki que podrían ser de utilidad:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7407,Main%20program%20property

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?17817,Native+Mobile+Main+object+properties

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14555,My%20first%20Android%20application

Con respecto al error 500.19, comúnmente sucede porque no se instaló el Url Rewrite:

https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18398,URLRewrite%20-%20Common%20issues

Saludos.